# Createsuperuser django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have recently change my model which is a personified model adding fields. After having done so I remove the file:

> 'db.sqlite3'

And launch:

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

The user creation via my application is fine but when I want to create a super user

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: website_dater.latitude
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a field called **latitude** in your model named like **website** which is not taking any null entry.
Either provide a value of latitude by default or use (null=True,blank=True) in defining that model,
Like this :

```
class Website(models.Model):
    ....
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

    # Or
    latitude = models.CharField(default='0')
```